# Trigger behaving strangely

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm making a Database that needs to store data for a school system and for certain activities minors need a permit.
I have this trigger that checks that if one participant is a minor, then he needs a permit.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION absent_permit()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
BEGIN
     RAISE NOTICE 'ENTERS TRIGGER';
     RAISE NOTICE 'AGE NEW PARTICIPANT = %', age_from_participant(NEW.id_part);
     IF (age_from_participant(NEW.id_part) < 18) AND (NEW.permit IS NULL) THEN
          RAISE NOTICE 'ENTERS IF';
          RAISE NOTICE 'PARTICIPANT UNDER 18 NEED A PERMIT';
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'MINOR WITHOUT PERMIT' USING HINT = 'PERMIT MUST BE != NULL';
          RETURN NULL;
     END IF;
     RAISE NOTICE 'EXIT TRIGGER';
     RETURN NEW;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER check_permit BEFORE INSERT ON participant
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE absent_permit();
```

Fact is: the first time i try to insert a minor without permit it doesn't work and insert it anyway, the second time I try instead of giving me an error due to the repeated primary key, the trigger works and raises the exception it should have raised the first time. The function age_from_participant works in the right way for sure and it's not the problem.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

EDIT: added table people, participant and example of insert

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    fiscal_code varchar(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    name        varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        surname         varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        phone       numeric(10, 0)  NOT NULL,
        sex             char(1)     NOT NULL    CHECK(sex IN ('M','F')),
        email       varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    d_birth     date            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE participant (
    id_part         varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    fiscal_code     varchar(16) NOT NULL    REFERENCES people(fiscal_code),
        documents_code      varchar(1000)   NOT NULL,
        section         varchar(2)  NOT NULL,
        grade           varchar(2)  NOT NULL,
        permit          varchar(500),
        school_code     varchar(10) NOT NULL    REFERENCES schools(school_code)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION age_from_participant(varchar)
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
     alias_id_part ALIAS FOR $1;
     precise_age interval;
BEGIN
    SELECT AGE(CURRENT_DATE, d_birth) INTO precise_age FROM participant
        JOIN PEOPLE USING(fiscal_code)
        WHERE PARTICIPANT.ID_PART = alias_id_part;
     RETURN date_part('year', precise_age)::INT;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


INSERT INTO people VALUES ('RSSMRC0123456789', 'MARCO', 'ROSSI', 3490101123, 'M', 'MARCOROSSI@GMAIL.COM', '2000-07-18');

INSERT INTO participant VALUES ('PART000001', 'RSSMRC0123456789','MR001','A','4',null, 'GEPC01000P');
```

With the last insert the first time it insert it right, console gives:

```
NOTICE:  ENTERS TRIGGER
NOTICE:  AGE NEW PARTICIPANT = 
NOTICE:  EXIT TRIGGER
INSERT 0 1
Query returned successfully.
```

The second time it gives:

```
ERROR:  MINOR WITHOUT PERMIT
HINT:  PERMIT MUST BE != NULL
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function absent_permit() line 8 at RAISE
********** Error **********

ERROR: MINOR WITHOUT PERMIT
SQL state: P0001
Hint: PERMIT MUST BE != NULL
Context: PL/pgSQL function absent_permit() line 8 at RAISE
```

EDIT_2:
I solved bringing the code of age_from_partecipant inside the trigger function. Still don't know exactly what didn't work but here it is the working code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION absent_permit()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
DECLARE
     age  interval;
BEGIN
SELECT AGE(CURRENT_DATE, D_birth) INTO age FROM participant JOIN people USING(fiscal_code) WHERE NEW.fiscal_code = people.fiscal_code;

     RAISE NOTICE 'ENTERS TRIGGER';
     RAISE NOTICE 'AGE NEW PARTICIPANT = %', date_part('year', age)::INT;
     IF (date_part('year', age)::INT < 18) AND (NEW.permit IS NULL) THEN
          RAISE NOTICE 'ENTERS IF';
          RAISE NOTICE 'PARTICIPANT UNDER 18 NEED A PERMIT';
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'MINOR WITHOUT PERMIT' USING HINT = 'PERMIT MUST BE != NULL';
          RETURN NULL;
     END IF;
     RAISE NOTICE 'EXIT TRIGGER';
     RETURN NEW;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER check_permit BEFORE INSERT ON participant
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE absent_permit();
```

Comment: You should be doing this with a check constraint, not a trigger.

Comment: I tried but couldn't make it work so I tried with a trigger

Comment: Can you post the definition of `età_from_participant`? Can you put a minimal example that actually shows the behaviour? (`CREATE table...`, `CREATE function`, `CREATE trigger`, ... `INSERT INTO  participant` ...)?

Comment: @joanolo I've edited and added the create tables and examples of the trigger

Comment: age_of_participant seems not to work in the insert trigger, as it is empty. Ithink you'll have to write it without the select of participant. Remember your insert trigger can't avoid illegal updates.

Comment: When you get `AGE NEW PARTICIPANT = (nothing)` you already know your problem. Probably the birth date of the participant is not yet in the database, or maybe there isn't *any* data about the participant, or your `JOIN PEOPLE USING(fiscal_code)` is making your code not to work, because you either don't have the participant  `fiscal_code`, or it is not on the `people` table...

Comment: @joanolo Now it works. I've taken the code of age_from_participant inside the function (with the same join) and it works. Besides, the data inside people was present (fiscal_code is the primary key and there was the birth date too), so I don't really know why it didn't work but now it does (I'll post the correct version editing the post)

Comment: @turo Now it works, I couldn't mention you in the answer before. I'll put the correct version in the next edit

Comment: You should take into account that you're on an *ON BEFORE* trigger: the *participant* is not yet on the table, even for your own transaction.

Comment: @joanolo I thought that the new. would solve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `età_from_participant()` can find the participant in `participant` -- because the transaction has not been completed.  That is, you have a *before* insert trigger.  The row is not in the table.

My suggestion is to move that logic directly into the trigger.  Or, alternatively, create an `età_from_person()` and pass the fiscal code into that function.

Comment: Solved thanks also to turo and joanolo in the comments, added the working code at the end of the post. Many thanks to everyone